# remove empty state in multiple columns of transition plot in R

Tags: r, plot, gmisc

I'm trying to use package `Gmisc` and make a three column transition plot in R, the data is like this `head(dat,10)`:

```
       ?.no X1 X2 X3
  1      2  S      
  2      6  E  E  E
  3     11  E      
  4     12  E      
  5     14  N      
  6     16  N      
  7     17  E  S   
  8     17  S  S   
  9     18  E      
  10    18  N
```

It has empty cells in both column 2 and 3. The result of  `dput(data)` is:

```
structure(list(?.no = c(2L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 58L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 171L, 173L, 179L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
184L, 185L, 188L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 211L, 213L, 215L, 218L, 
219L, 221L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 232L, 268L), X1 = c("S", "E", "E", 
"E", "N", "N", "E", "S", "E", "N", "E", "E", "E", "S", "N", "E", 
"E", "S", "E", "N", "E", "E", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "N", "E", "S", "E", "E", "N", "E", "S", "N", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "N", "N", "E", "E", "E", "E"), X2 = c("", "E", "", 
"", "", "", "S", "S", "", "", "E", "", "", "", "E", "", "", "", 
"", "E", "E", "", "E", "", "", "E", "", "", "", "", "", "E", 
"N", "", "", "", "", "", "", "E", "", "", "E", "", "", "S", "", 
"", "", ""), X3 = c("", "E", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "E", "", "", "", "", "E", "E", "", "E", "", "", 
"E", "", "", "", "", "", "", "N", "", "", "", "", "", "", "E", 
"", "", "E", "", "", "N", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("?.no", 
"X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L
))
```

The code for the transition plot :

```
library(Gmisc)
library(magrittr) 
clr<-c("darkblue","orange","darkgreen")
clr1<-c("grey","darkblue","orange","darkgreen")
transitions <- table(dat$X1,dat$X2)%>%
  getRefClass("Transition")$new(label=c("1st", "2nd"))
transitions$fill_clr[[1]] = clr;
transitions$fill_clr[[2]] = clr1;
table(dat$X2,dat$X3) %>% transitions$addTransitions(label = '3rd')
transitions$render()
```

the output:

[transition plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1s77.jpg)

And then I have two problems:

1 some narrow arrows cannot be visualized. my first transition matrix `table(dat$X1,dat$X2)` is like this:

```
        E  N  S
  E 23  4  1  1
  N  7  6  0  1
  S  6  0  0  1
```

But the arrows from N to S and S to S are missing. The third column as well
`table(dat$X2,dat$X2)`

```
        E  N
    36  0  0
  E  2  8  0
  N  0  0  1
  S  2  0  1
```

2 So because there are so much empty value to distract attention (shown in grey in figure), I would like to remove the empty value which means the record don't have any category at next stage/column. I'm interested on the records which have value for all three stages but still want to keep the origin data set to show the proportion. The question is similar to  [Transition State Diagram R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769650/transition-state-diagram-r?newreg=077424acc18244cdb7ead21cd70095d1) But I have empty values at both 2 and 3 column.

Basically, what I did is to remove empty values from the second and third column, by using the same ways as mentioned in precious link,  manually set the `transitions$transitions` to 0. But the figure turns out to be wrong
[transition plot after remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHoYy.jpg) , compare to the origin figure, the proportion of blue and orange changed, it apparently because I changed the `transitions$transitions` .

Is there any other way to remove the empty values without changing `transitions$transitions`? Simply just remove some  certain boxes and arrow linked to those boxes?

Of course I understand, the empty value could be treat as a new category and I could simply keep as it is, but those empty value is meaningless for my study question thus I wish to get ride of them.

Hope I explain it well and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is what the `min_lwd` is for:

```
transitions$min_lwd <- 0.01
```

I'm not sure I follow you on the second part of your question. The sizes of the plot are directly proportional to the inputs.

Comment: Thanks very much for answer of the first question. It works amazing and I love the output! I edited my second question and hope to explain it in a better way.

Comment: I don't think I added a way to remove boxes, you do that in the input data as you tried